# split string to three doubles

Tags: c#, string, split

I used C# and I would like split text comprised 3 doubles seperated by commas and spaces.

I did:

```
double[] doubles = mystr.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' })
                .Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s))
                .ToArray();
```

when mystr = 33,44,55 for example it works fine (numbers seperated by only one comma)

Also, when mystr= 33 44 55 for example it works fine (numbers seperated by only one space)

BUT, when mystr= 33, 44, 55 it doesn't works (one space after the comma between each two numbers)

It also doesn't work when mystr = 33  44  55 (two spaces between each two numbers)

In both above examples I got an unhandled exception.

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: `Regex.Replace(yourstring.Text, " ", "");`

Comment: Beware, if the double comes from a system which it's decimal separator is a comma it will fail unless it's writen with System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try specifying [`StringSplitOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), and use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to remove empty strings..

```
    double[] doubles = mystr.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(Convert.ToDouble)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: @Programmer -- I want to point out that Jonathan Nappee's answer should be accepted in all fairness since it's pretty much identical to this answer and was posted *before* this answer was (if you hover your cursor over the "answered X hours ago"

Answer (score 10):

You can add an option to remove empty entries in the Split:

```
var array = Array.ConvertAll(mystr.Split(new [] { ' ', ',' },
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
                             Convert.ToDouble);
```

Comment: for using `Array.ConvertAll()` +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`:

```
var pattern = @"(\d+)((,\s*|\s+)|$)";
const int RegexTimeoutSeconds = 1;
var matches = Regex.Matches(mystr, pattern, RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(RegexTimeoutSeconds));
var doubles = new List<double>();

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var group = match.Groups[1];
    var d = Convert.ToDouble(group.Value);
    doubles.Add(d);
}
```

Comment: This regex will only work if there is at least one comma and one space.  The first example of "33,44,55" will fail.  I think you probably want `"[, ]+"` for the Regex string.